# Api url with http or https in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I want to ask about working with APIs in flutter.

API domain is:
`https://example.com`

Due to some reasons if SSL of domain expires

Then App stops working.
How can we set if SSL expires then use domain with `http` until SLL renew.

I am setting BASE_URL:
`static const String BASE_URL = 'http://example.com`your text`';

Thanks

Suddenly my domain's SSL expired. Renewal of SSL took some time.
I opened my app and it stopped on the splash screen.
Then I checked it on the android emulator it was giving an error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the ssl expires, the settings of server with redirect and reapplying will remain, they shall come in the way of your coding.